# jQuery sum values (text) of all lis to the parent ones

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I have tried to find an answer a few hours long but all i found did not solve my problem
I have a bunch of nested unordered lists where in the last level there are values in a span

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>
            <span>0</span>
        </a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>
                    <span>0</span>
                </a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a>
                            <span>1</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>
                            <span>2</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>            
        </ul>
    </li>
     <li>
        <a>
            <span>0</span>
        </a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>
                    <span>0</span>
                </a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a>
                            <span>5</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>
                            <span>6</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>            
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to sum this values to the above elements span
My code looks following.

```
$($("li a span").get().reverse()).each(function()
             {
                 var itemValue = parseInt($(this).text());
                 var parentSpan = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find("a span:first");
                 var parentVal= parseInt(parentSpan.text());
                 parentVal=parentVal + itemValue;
                 parentSpan.text(parentVal.toString());
             });
```

this results in the following

```
28  <-- here is the problem ...
    3
        1
        2
11
    11
        5
        6
```

The first li sums also all the other li in the same level
what i expected was that only the sublevels should sum up to the parent level like in the second part

### expected result:

```
3   <-- this should only count childs not same level elements
    3
        1
        2
11
    11
        5
        6
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Thanks in advance
Don

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try putting below code, Hope this will help you.

```
var $topUl = $($('ul')[0]);
$.each($topUl.children('li'), function(index, val){
$ulEle = $(val).children('ul');
var sum1 = 0;
$.each($ulEle.children('li'), function(index, val){
    var sum2 = 0;
    $.each($(val).find('ul span'), function(index2, val){
        sum2+=parseInt($(val).text());
    });
    $(val).children('a').find('span').text(sum2);
    sum1+=sum2;
});
$(val).children('a').find('span').text(sum1);
});
```

Comment: Vikram, you saved my day! thanks a lot - I tried to vote up your anwer but i am sorry - it seems i am not aloowed to do so ..